# Using htaccess to shorten URL with variables

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to use an htaccess file, in order to change a URL such as this:

http://example.com/index.php?a=profile&u=username123

into this?:

http://example.com/username123

If so, how would I go about this? Sorry if this question is very basic.

Comment: I think this question doesn't show much research effort. There are probably thousands of examples, but a quick search for "htaccess nice urls" gave [this article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049) as a first result, which shows how you can redirect an url like `domain.tld/username` to `domain.tld/profile.php?id=username`.

Comment: I don't think you put much effort into reading my question. I'm looking at something opposite of what you're giving an example of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect old format to new format (remove the 2 following lines if you don't want this)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\?a=profile&u=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

# Internally rewrite every non-existing file/folder in root folder to old format
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?a=profile&u=$1 [L]
```

Don't forget to make sure that *mod_rewrite* is enabled and htaccess allowed (in apache configuration)